# Create user to see only one view in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, view, permissions

I want to have user with permission to see only one view.

I have created that user that can't see any other tables or view but can select anything

**QUESTION**

Why I can lock user to do any select insert / update?

Answer (score 2):

LOGIN and USER should have only one role: public.

Next, grant select permission for that user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON **schema.VIEW_NAME** TO [**USER_NAME**]
```

Full script:

```
CREATE LOGIN [TEST] WITH PASSWORD=N'PASS', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DATABASE_NAME]
GO
USE [test]
GO
CREATE USER [TEST] FOR LOGIN [TEST]
GO

GRANT SELECT ON schema.VIEW_NAME TO [TEST]
GO
```

Login to DB using login TEST and check if you could select.

Comment: ok, but after i dont see other tables and view.. BUT I CAN WRITE ANY query any select from any table

Comment: this not work i find the solution
it is
i must close all permissions
Deny Select on table to login 
and do this for all tables , views , sp s, and with all commands (select, alter, update, delete)